# Can I do a second pass Elastic Net only including the most significant predictors?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, elastic-net

First off, I am new to predictive modeling and I appreciate any advice.

BACKGROUND:

I am doing a binomial elastic net where n = 54 and p = 89. This model is for predicting drug effects clinically; thus, prediction by measuring as few variables as possible would be ideal.

After Elastic Net variable selection/shrinkage, 24 predictors are included in the model. Of the 24 predictors included in the model, 10 are significant predictors and contribute 96% of the total effects in the model (link to calculation below).

QUESTION: Can I generate a second predictive model using only the top 10 predictors from my first elastic net? I would like to demonstrate that as few as 10 variables could be used for prediction. If so, would the second pass be better with elastic net or another model type?

CALCULATIONS:

I am doing my predictive modeling using JMP Pro statistical software. This software calculates the effect contributions of each variable as they describe [here](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/en/16.2/#page/jmp/assess-variable-importance.shtml?os=win&source=application#ww376802).

and briefly here:
Independent Resampled Inputs
For each factor, Monte Carlo samples are obtained by resampling its set of observed values. Use this option when you believe that your factors are uncorrelated and that their likely values are not represented by a uniform distribution"

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! If you want ten variables, might it make more sense to crank up the penalty until you only have ten nonzero coefficients?

Comment: Thank you, @Dave ! Just implemented your suggestion. Cranking penalty up to .4 left ten nonzero coefficients, as you suggested. I note the p-values for the ten variables are dramatically increased compared to using a lower penalty (some are no longer significant) and the 95% confidence intervals are wider. Whereas, if I include only the 10 most significant variables in a second pass with a penalty of .1, most variables have p values <.05 and the confidence intervals are tight. Am I introducing errors with a second pass that are causing inflated p values? Apologies for my ignorance! Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting p-values and confidence intervals for your LASSO coefficients?

Comment: The ChiSquare value for a Wald test of whether the parameter is zero is calculated, then the prob > ChiSquare is reported. [here](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/en/16.2/#page/jmp/parameter-estimates-for-original-predictors.shtml?os=win&source=application#ww312230) the output is described by JMP, the statistical software I'm using in case it's helpful. The confidence interval explanation from JMP is somewhat lacking..."The lower/upper bound for a 95% confidence interval for the parameter". Still learning to code, unfortunately, so stat software is my best option and this is what's reported!

Comment: That makes it sound like a regular test as if you did not include a penalty term. If that is the case, I would not trust those p-values or confidence intervals.

Comment: Ah, I'm so glad to know that, thank you. Perhaps comparing parameter estimate values is more trustworthy -- the parameter estimates are actually quite similar between the two methods. I see there is a plethora of discussions regarding calculating the significance of parameter estimates on Stack Exchange, so I will review those and calculate p-values differently. Thank you so much for your time and help @Dave !